# How can I perfectly copy a POST request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, post, python-requests

Say I picked up a POST request with my chrome developer tools. How can I copy that POST request exactly, so that I can send that exact same request with the python requests module.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

1. Open chrome developers tools -> right click -> Copy -> Copy as cURL
2. Translate the `curl` command into Python `requests` online [here](https://curl.trillworks.com/) or using [uncurl](https://github.com/spulec/uncurl) package:

```
import uncurl

print(uncurl.parse("curl 'https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uncurl' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch'"))

# output:
'requests.get("https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uncurl", headers={
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate,sdch",
})'
```